# React Native Fetch Load Error

Tags: react-native, fetch, expo

I've just started working with React Native to develop mobile apps. I want to use Fetch to make GET requests for geoprocessing services on my company's server. I'm working with [this](https://github.com/tiaanduplessis/react-native-fetch) example and I keep getting this error in Expo: **Cannot read property 'string' of undefined**. I get this error even when I just import Fetch at the top of the script, without the rest of the code.

Comment: Can you please share snack expo link?

Comment: It would probably be better to open an issue there

Comment: I entered my code on snack expo and got this error: Device: (741:5091) Failed to install module 'react-native-fetch': undefined is not an object (evaluating 'f.PropTypes.string')  https://snack.expo.io/S1LfI66-f

Comment: I didn't get that error, but you could try `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';`

Comment: I added that import and still got the "Cannot read property 'string' of undefined" error. Also got "Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)"

Comment: I getting errors if I try to import anything from the node-modules. https://snack.expo.io/SyNmvTpZf